# Compare each splitted result with each class element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, jquery-selectors

```
var data = 'sky,sea,earth,moon';
var a = data.split(","), i;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var b = a[i].text();
    $('mdcatsitem').each(function(){
        if (b == $(this).text()) {$(this).addClass('toggleright');}
    });
}
```

Console:
`Uncaught TypeError: a[i].text is not a function`

What I need:
- split `data` into parts;
- get text of `each` part and compare it to text of `each` `mdcatsitem`;
- if matched - add a class to `mdcatsitem`

Comment: `$('mdcatsitem').filter(function(i, el) { return a.includes(el.textContent) }).addClass('toggleright')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `a[i].text()` with `a[i]`.

`a[i]` is **not** a *dom element* **but** a *string*. `a` is an array after you `split` the `data`.

```
a = ['sky', 'sea', 'earth', 'moon']
```

Use this code:

```
var data = 'sky,sea,earth,moon';
var a = data.split(","), i;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var b = a[i];
    $('mdcatsitem').each(function(){
        if (b == $(this).text()) {$(this).addClass('toggleright');}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you calling `.text()` on a string?

`data` is a delimited string, and after you call `.split()` on it then `a` is simply an array of strings:

```
['sky', 'sea', 'earth', 'moon']
```

When looping over `a`, you can just reference `a[i]` directly as the string you want:

```
var b = a[i];
// b now equals the string, such as 'sky' or 'sea'
```